# mysql join not returning the expected ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table. I want to join them.

This  table is "program_participants"

[image: program_participants]

This table is "logsesion"

[image]

My query

```
    SELECT a.`id_participant` FROM `program_participants` a
INNER JOIN `logsesion` b
on a.`id_participant` != b.`user_id`
GROUP BY a.`id_participant`
```

Now after running the query above I get a.`id_participant` (1 to 9 means all of it from participants table) But I want all of it except 1 and 2 as they are present in the logsesion table. can you please tell me what I am doing wrong. I have spend so much time on this and this seems to be straight forward. I have also tried symbol <> as well.

Comment: you really should edit your post by removing password hashes with there account names (e-mail), looks like md5 which is unsafe, even if its a internal project, user often use same passwords on other locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `left join` and then a comparison to filter out the records that match.  The ones that remain have no match:

```
SELECT pa.`id_participant`
FROM `program_participants` pa LEFT JOIN
     `logsesion` ls
     ON pa.`id_participant` = ls.`user_id`
WHERE ls.user_id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but something like this shoul work:

```
SELECT a.`id_participant` FROM `program_participants` a
LEFT JOIN `logsesion` b
ON a.`id_participant` = b.`user_id`
GROUP BY a.`id_participant`
HAVING b.`user_id` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to join these table you can try this, this will give the cartesian product of these tables filtering the userids already in the logsesion table. If you want different results comment below:

```
SELECT pa.`id_participant`
FROM `program_participants` pa JOIN
     `logsesion` ls
WHERE pa.`id_participant` NOT IN 
(
 SELECT user_id from `logsesion`
);
```